# R Data frame operations

Tags: r, dataframe

Im trying to do some operations using data frame rows. Let’s say I have the next data frame:

```
Label<-c(‘A’, ‘A’,’B’,’B’,’A’,’B’,’A’,’X’,’Y’)
Var <- c(1,2,4,7,3,4,6,10,13)
Data<- data.frame(Label,Var)
```

I want that, when Label=A, The value in Var is multiplied by X, and when label=B, multiplied by Y.

I was trying to write a function but without success, probably I’m lacking experience working with data frames.

I’ll be thankful for any help!

Comment: Should it be changed both in the function at one call?  Perhaps `f1 <- function(labl, val){ i1 <- Data[['Label']] == labl; Data[['Var']][i1] <- Data[['Var']][i1] * val; Data}` and then do the testing `f1("A", 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a good old but simple `base` solution?

```
X <- 3
Y <- 2
Data$NewVar <- with(Data, ifelse(Label == "A", Var * X, Var * Y))
Data
  Label Var NewVar
1     A   1      3
2     A   2      6
3     B   4      8
4     B   7     14
5     A   3      9
6     B   4      8
7     A   6     18
8     X  10     20
9     Y  13     26
```

`ifelse` evaluates if the first condition is true, then the next statement will be evaluated, else the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn’t know ifelse function

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

Label<-c(‘A’, ‘A’,’B’,’B’,’A’,’B’,’A’,’X’,’Y’)
Var <- c(1,2,4,7,3,4,6,10,13)
Dat <- data_frame(Label,Var) #use data_frame and don't call the dataframe 'Data'

Dat <- Dat %>% # a pipe moves to next command
         mutate( #to create a new variable
           new_var = 
            case_when( #runs a series of ifelse statements
              Label == 'A' ~ Var*X, #framework: if ~ then
              Label == 'B' ~ Var*Y
         )
       )
```